# moved static s3 site to cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

We had been serving our images from a static web address on s3. Doing this we were able to use lambda to create new dimensions of the images based on the URL e.g `mys3domain.com/1200x900/imagejpg` we wanted to serve these images from https which is something static web adress on s3 does support so we have moved away from s3 to cloudfront, however when requesting images where dimensions don't exists instead of lambda being trigged we get a 404 response. I am assuming I need to change my lambda trigger but I am not sure how?

Comment: How is it working prior to CloudFront? There are no S3 event triggers associated with S3 GET afaik. Also, this could be helpful: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/resizing-images-with-amazon-cloudfront-lambdaedge-aws-cdn-blog/

Comment: My lambda function was triggered on api gateway event.

Comment: Did you configure an Origin Path in CloudFront? Remove it and re-test.